# How to apply individual parameters to easing in transitions?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, easing

I make a transition to objects like

```
.transition()
.duration(600)
.delay(function(d, i) { return (500 - (i * 40)); })
.ease(d3.easeBackInOut)
```

In the documentation there are different parameters possible to manipulate the type of easing like `backInOut(t, 3.0)` but I do not know how to apply `t` and a different amplitude...
Any help on that?

https://github.com/d3/d3-ease#easeBackInOut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the specific case of `d3.easeBackInOut` you can set the amplitude (called *overshoot* in the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-ease#back_overshoot)) by using `overshoot()`:

```
.ease(d3.easeBackInOut.overshoot(s))
//your value here----------------^
```

Here is a demo using `3` as the overshoot (the default value is 1.70158):

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 100)
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("r", 10)
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .style("fill", "lightgray")
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .ease(d3.easeBackInOut.overshoot(3))
  .attr("cx", 400);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

By the way, you don't need to mess with `t`. Its value, going from 0 to 1, is automatically passed to the easing function.

Comment: And i did not understand "back" in the API: `# back.overshoot(s) <>`

Comment: `back` is just the name for that group of easing: `d3.easeBackIn`, `d3.easeBackOut`, `d3.easeBack` and `d3.easeBackInOut`.